# read contents of .pst file with php

Tags: php, outlook, pst

Is it possible to somehow use PHP to read the contents of a .pst file?

Comment: I am not aware of a library that does this. Your best bet would be to use the [COM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php).

Comment: I doubt it, PST is a rather complex closed format. See the FAQ at this page: http://www.mailnavigator.com/reading_ms_outlook_pst_files.html

Comment: This is no longer true, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's a standalone program to convert PST to other formats (which may be then readable using PHP extensions, e.g. php_imap): http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/

However, as Microsoft keeps changing the PST format, it's not guaranteed that you'll be able to convert all PST files.

Comment: At least since your answer in 2010 it hasn't been changed anymore, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Exporting folders from MS Outlook (FILE -> OPEN -> IMPORT -> EXPORT TO A FILE) into plain text CSV enables easy parsing e.g. via [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function. The `libpst` is only supported on linux (RPM).

[Format of PST file](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-PST/[MS-PST].pdf) is complex and parsing it with PHP would be a tremendous job.