# Beginner's guide towards a linux based solution to read mail content (including attachments) from MS Outlook's .pst files

Tags: linux, parsing, email, outlook, pst

I have just started with the basics of how MS Outlook stores its mails in its own format (.pst format) and I have to deliver a script (search something or write my own) which -

- parses these .pst files on a **linux system** (which were zipped and sent here)
- creates a single .txt file for every mail. Creates a single .zip file for every attachment. This is the basic thing to be done. I also need to assign some unique names to the text files to be created.
- Any language - PHP, Java, Python - whichever is available/applicable.

**Some basic Questions**
 Would be nice if anyone could clarify these basic questions -

- Are both mail contents as well as attachment info stored as .pst files?

**I got these so far**

- [Read contents of .pst file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222920/read-contents-of-pst-file-with-php)
- [How can I dump emails from an Outlook .pst file into a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885539/how-can-i-dump-emails-from-an-outlook-pst-file-into-a-mysql-database) says that

> Google email uploader (open source),
>   they do the reading part...

- In this question - [Outlook PST File Parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197388/outlook-pst-file-parsing-in-python), there is mention about libpst-python.

Any suggestions regarding which of these solutions or some others to try? Or if you could tell about any of your experiences so that I get an idea before actually trying out any solution and later realizing it is not possible that way. Any pointers would be appreciated. I basically come from a LAMP background with little knowledge in other languages. Have done a little bit of bash programming recently.

Thanks,
Sandeepan

**Update**
JPST works fine. There are modules exactly for these things - read all messages (you can simple write code to save in files), save the attachments and many other things.

Also I came to know that mail contents as well as attachments, all are stored in the .pst files.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at either http://alioth.debian.org/projects/libpst/ or http://www.genusa.com/utils/pmseu.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider Aspose.Network for parsing Outlook PST files. In Linux environment, there are 2 ways to parse PST with Aspose.Network.

1. Use [Aspose.Network for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.network-for-java/default.aspx). This requires Sun's JDK and will run natively on Linux, because Aspose.Network for Java library is written in Java. [Here](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.network-for-java/extract-messages-from-outlook-pst-file-and-save-to-disk-or-stream-in-msg-format.html) is a sample Java program for exporting MSG files from PST.
2. Use [Aspose.Network for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.network-for-.net/default.aspx) with Mono on Linux. This solution depends on Mono for running .NET code in Linux environment, because the Aspose.Network for .NET library is written purely in .NET. [Here](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.network-for-.net/extract-messages-from-outlook-pst-file-and-save-to-disk-or-stream-in-msg-format.html) is the sample .NET program for exporting messages (MSG) from PST.